# Oracle viewing highest record

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have a Module and Students table as well as a linker table called Results. I am trying to display only one record of the student with the highest result for the specific module but i cannot get it to work. Here is my sql syntax so far:

```
SELECT S.ST_FNAME, S.ST_LNAME, M.MOD_NAME, R.RES_GRADE
FROM STUDENT S, MODULE M, RESULTS R
WHERE S.ST_ID=R.ST_ID AND M.MOD_ID=R.MOD_ID
AND M.MOD_ID=503;
```

At the moment it displays all the students and their results for the specific module.

help would be appreciated

Comment: Use the [MAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj27781.html) function to select something with the highest value.

Comment: I've been trying, but cant seem to get it right

Answer (score 1):

To get a single value for a group of rows, use GROUP BY (in your case, with MAX to get the maximum):

```
SELECT 
  S.ST_FNAME, 
  S.ST_LNAME, 
  M.MOD_NAME, 
  max(R.RES_GRADE) as max_grade
FROM STUDENT S
JOIN RESULTS R on S.ST_ID = R.ST_ID
JOIN MODULE M on R.MOD_ID = M.MOD_ID
WHERE M.MOD_ID=503
GROUP BY s.st_fname, s.st_lname, m.mod_name;
```

I've also converted your old-style joins to ANSI-style joins - using ANSI style is preferred by most people nowadays.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/756ce/2)

Comment: s.ST_ID = 503 and m.MOD_ID= 503 are two different things

Comment: i assume you meant to write m.mod_id=503 instead of s.st_id. I've changed it and it still shows me all 3 results, instead of one top result that i want. any advice?

Comment: @user3112130 You may want to make sure that there is no duplicate data in your tables. SELECT st_fname, st_lname from student group by st_fname, st_lname having count(*) > 1; And again, SELECT mod_name from MODULE group by mod_name having count(*) > 1;

Comment: @user3112130 You're right about the mod_id, of course. Fixed. If you still don't get the correct results, please add your example data to your question, as well as the output you're expecting.